# MS Project: Week, Resource, Project crosstab view

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010, reporting

I have MS Project 2010 server.

I need to add view or report (whatever fits best), and it may be implemented on client or server (whatever fits best).

I need a crosstab report where Resources will be on one axis, Weeks on another and project list in cells.

Result should look like this:

```
                | Alice      | Bob  | Jim  |
--------------------------------------------
Dec  3 - Dec  9 | Prj1       | Prj1 |      |
Dec 10 - Dec 16 | Prj1       | Prj2 | Prj2 | 
Dec 17 - Dec 23 | Prj1, Prj2 | Prj2 | Prj2 |
Dec 24 - Dec 30 | Prj2       | Prj2 | Prj3 |
```

Of course it is acceptable if resources will be vertical, and weeks horizontal.

How should I do this? I tried to setup custom resource assignments view on server but did not succ

Maybe that was discussed already, but I did not find any answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a way to generate this report using the built-in reporting features (even with a custom report format). You say that you can run it on the client -- are you able to run VBA? If so, you could generate this using a custom VBA function.

Answer (score 3):

The Resource View will have the Resources listed in a column. The Row headings can be the time span - days, or weeks or months. For each resource, the projects they are working on will be shown.

Wouldn't this, automatically available Resource View, suffice ?